# Why doesn't this onchange event work?

Tags: javascript

```
if (!localStorage.text) localStorage.text = document.body.innerHTML;

function ifChanged() {
    document.body.innerHTML.onchange = function() {
        if (document.body.innerHTML !== (localStorage.text)) alert("No match");
    };
}

ifChanged();
```

It doesn't check if it changed. What went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because the [`onchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange) is for form fields (it fires when the field's value changes). It is not fired when the *HTML* changes, just, for example, when a user types a key in a textbox.

The best way to know when something on the page changes is to have the code that is making the changes in the first place signal that a change is being made (this could be cleanly done with some sort of event broadcast).

If you really want to do it this way, you could use a timer that periodically polls for changes:

```
setInterval(ifChanged, 1000);    // Check once every second (1000ms)
```

Answer (score 4):

`document.body.innerHTML` returns a string and `String.onChange` and `String.setEventListener('change', ...);` are undefined.
The DOM 2 introduce [MutationEvents](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) which will fire when the DOM is changed. Unfortunately, those events are not widely implemented and may [slow down every change in the DOM](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.platform/browse_thread/thread/2f42f1d75bb906fb).